# Getting the job id of a chained job from the id of the parent job

Tags: apex, asynchronous, asyncapexjob

I have a Queueable job that will initiate a Batch job. I have a transaction that enqueues the Queueable job and returns the id of the Queueable job. However, I need to be able to get the id of the Batch job programatically in a separate transaction (likely using the id of the Queueable job that started it). I was under the impression that I can do this in Apex but see no fields for querying in the documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.212.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_asyncapexjob.htm). Does anyone know how I can get the follow-up job's Id from the parent job's Id?

Comment: What's the objective? Are you trying to poll for the batch job's conclusion?

Comment: Exactly. I want to know when the job is done to run some post-processing/verifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to determine the parent of a job by way of a query. Instead, you'll have to arrange for a different means of getting the ID. You could use a Custom Setting to store the data, or perhaps the Platform Cache, or a record. The Queueable will need to store that data in the database for future use. I kind of wonder why you'd want to call a queueable just to call the batchable, but that's your design decision. It just kind of sounds inefficient.

Comment: Yeah. I've started to ask the same question. The job initially was not a batch job, which is why it was not a concern but now that it is, I may need to redesign the application. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than trying to pass fragile, information-poor async job ids across a chain of asynchronous functionality, I'd suggest using a  custom object, say `Async_Job__c`, to persist an overarching job id and job status. Your UI code, or whatever is firing the first job in the chain, would generate its own id (some meaningful, unique string) and retain it.

Each async class should have a constructor that takes a String job id and retains it for the duration of its processing, and then passes that same id along when it initializes and fires the next job, along the way also updating the status of the job. E.g. from your Queueable

```
Async_Job__c myJob = [SELECT Id FROM Async_Job__c WHERE Job_Id__c = :myJobIdString LIMIT 1];

// Mark that we completed processing (or record any errors)
myJob.Job_Status__c = 'Queueable complete, launching batch.';
update myJob;
// Initialize a batch job and pass along our persistent id so it 
// can also update the Async_Job__c record
Database.executeBatch(new BatchJob(myJobIdString));
```

The batch can then similarly update the `Async_Job__c` record with its status, or, critically, with any errors that take place. Your UI code can periodically poll this record to determine the status of the entire sequence of jobs, using the persistent job id that it originally generated and retains.

Comment: This is in a managed package and I won't be able to add a new object unfortunately because of all the extra complexities it may add.

Comment: You've got to persist the job details somehow. sfdcfox had a couple of other ideas (platform cache/custom settings), both of which have their own complexities. In an architecture this complex, I would take a step back and consider if it can either (a) be refactored to reduce the complexity or (b) if you need to bite the bullet and implement a complex solution to a complex problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you are just trying to get the Id of the executed batch within the same context, the `Database.executeBatch` method returns it.

```
public void execute(QueueableContext context)
{
    Id batchJobId = Database.executeBatch(new MyBatch());
}
```

Comment: thanks. I know I can do this. The problem is I need to get the job id in a separate transaction. I updated the question to clarify.